# Is module.exports unique to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js

I'm stepping through some client-side JavaScript code that code like:

```
       (function() {
            'use strict';﻿
            debugger; //TODO
            module.exports = function(utils, e)
```

Called by:

```
return require(name, dirname(path));
```

Does this mean that it's using node.js?  This is client-side code that's using Backbone and JQuery.

-Eric

Comment: Possibly. I use [a variation of the UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/returnExportsGlobal.js) that allows me to export my code both to window and as a commonJS module for testing in nodeJS.

Answer (score 3):

No.

This pattern is called [CommonJS Modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules); Node.js merely implemenets the pattern.

There are a number of implementations that run in the browser; [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is the most popular.